# c sockets mysterious slowdown on air-gapped Linux laptop

Tags: c, performance, sockets

I coded a simple echo server (from http://gnosis.cx/publish/programming/sockets.html) in C and everything worked well on localhost.  Then I decided to try connecting in a tight loop of 10,000 'client' hits to the server.  It failed immediately claiming that I had opened too many files.  So I scaled back to 1022 and it worked (1022 connections made, data sent and received).  I also found that I could override the upper limit (which also worked, 4094 in non-privileged, lots - 1M? - in privileged mode).  I was feeling pretty good, but before I got into doing things like `select()` or `epoll()`, I decided to stress-test the non-privileged run.  I can connect and send 4000 (I avoided the vicinity of 4096) times in about 0.5 seconds (without `printf()` logging).  I can do that three times in a row with almost identical timings.  The fourth time takes about 6.0 seconds. And then I get times of around 11.0 seconds.  Same client program (sending 4000 5-letter words) UNCHANGED server program (with only FIVE as a value for `MAXPENDING`)...  After about 3 or four runs where I wait for 11.2097 seconds, it goes back to 0.5 seconds (for three) and then 6 seconds, and then 11 seconds again. -- It FEELS like I'm using up some kind of pool (around 12 or 13,000?) that is there for the taking, and then needs to be garbage collected.... slowly...  I would gladly do things differently, but I don't know what the problem or its solution.  I also moved the server to a VM with its own IP `addr` with absolutely identical results.  Can anyone tell me what might be going on behind the scenes and what the best practice is to manage it?

I thought it might be solved by the `setsockopt(TCP_NODELAY)` to suppress Nagle's algorithm, but the results are identical: .5, .5, .5, 6, 11, 11, 11
It'll temporarily 'crash' the server for a few seconds if I repeat as fast as possible.  But eventually ('crash' or no 'crash'), we're back in business round-tripping 4000 'echoes' in 0.5 seconds.

running gcc on 64-bit Ubuntu 18.04... gcc -v gives me:

```
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 


for(i=0; i<CLIENT; i++)
{
    if (connect(sock[i], (struct sockaddr *) &echoserver[i], sizeof(echoserver[i])) < 0) Die("Failed to connect with server");

    echolen = strlen(argv[2]);
    if (send(sock[i], argv[2], echolen, 0) != echolen) Die("!");

    while (received < echolen) {
      int bytes = 0;
      if ((bytes = recv(sock[i], buffer[i], BUFFSIZE-1, 0)) < 1) Die("!rcv");
      received += bytes;
      buffer[i][bytes] = '\0';
    }
    close(sock[i]);
}
```

Comment: Can you include the relevant code in the question and not as an external link? This helps keep your question self-contained and focused on the problem.

Comment: I'm presuming "before I got into doing things like select() or epoll()`" means you're flooding the write buffer without realizing it. You need `select` or equivalent to tell you when the socket is *ready to write* and you must pay attention or the stack will just throw out your writes.

Comment: Running netstat on your computer after each test might be informative -- TCP sockets often stick around in the kernel for a short time after they are closed by the program (to avoid unintended reuse of old connections, IIRC), and it might be the kernel's socket-table that is getting temporarily filled up.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on "*It'll temporarily 'crash' the server for a few seconds*"?

Comment: The link that I included has code for both an echo server and an echo client.  I copied both programs, character for character from this machine to my air-gapped machine.  So... in the code (I just copied) below, where it says "Die("failed to connect to server");"  that's what I mean by 'crash'ing.  Obviously the server didn't crash, but the error message hinted at a connectivity issue.  Here is the relevant code (the client code) without link:             (in a minute - it's too long to just post the whole program)

Comment: `
  for(i=0; i<CLIENT; i++)
  {
...
    if (connect(sock[i], (struct sockaddr *) &echoserver[i], sizeof(echoserver[i])) < 0) Die("Failed to connect with server");

    echolen = strlen(argv[2]);
    if (send(sock[i], argv[2], echolen, 0) != echolen) Die("!");

    while (received < echolen) {
      int bytes = 0;
      if ((bytes = recv(sock, buffer, BUFFSIZE-1, 0)) < 1) Die("!rcv");
      received += bytes;
      buffer[bytes] = '\0';
    }
    close(sock[i]);
  }
`

Comment: thanks, tadman, I probably am flooding the write buffer.  I'll check it out.

Comment: `if ((bytes = recv(sock[i], buffer[i], BUFFSIZE-1, 0)) < 1) Die("!rcv");` if read or write return -1, you should always check `errno` , and act appropiately.

Answer (score 0):

Netstat wins the day.  Thanks commentator Jeremy Friesner.  The trouble was the sockets remained open in a `TIME_WAIT` state.  Of course I'll continue to try to wriggle around that one.  It seems like `TIME_WAIT` is an inevitability.  If so, I'd like to be able to up the System's `MAX_OPEN` to a value larger than 16384.  Comments on that one are more than welcome.  If I solve it, I'll comment, myself.  `TIME_WAIT` lasts precisely 60 seconds on my laptop.  How do I know this?  `date; netstat | wc`... I'll be honest, I've never been a big fan of netstat, netcat, nc, or other systools that spew volumes of info.  But that was the silly, pre-enlightened me.  netstat good.  Thanks to the other commentors who nudged me in the right direction, as well.  Thanks, man named tad...  Thanks, just alk...